# How to make an iframe automatically refresh without refreshing the whole page and flikering

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

So I am trying to make a chat room in html it is really basic but i would like to make the iframe i use to display my messages automatically refresh but without flikering how would i do that

i have tried

using this

```
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 100);
function reloadIFrame() {
document.getElementById("commentsframe").src="http://billischill.ddns.net/chatfile.html";
}
```

but the whole iframe flikers when it refreshes and i cant have that

this here is my  [url](http://billischill.ddns.net)

its pretty weird but i dont care i am trying to make it better

if you have any sugestions just leave it in the chat please

Comment: There is no way of doing this as far as I know. If you don't want the page to flicker then you shouldn't be refreshing it. Instead you should load new content via AJAX.

Comment: how would i do that do i have to have a server side language instaled

Comment: There are many tutorials that can get you started, like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: It looks really cool but i dont know how to install it on my Imac

Comment: so its not server side?? is it already there i dont have to install anything

Comment: you may use a load function in AJAX. But be careful about the crossDomain error.

Comment: How should i do that ??

Comment: i have never used ajax in my life can you please help